# Django: How to write a mock/patch test for object creation?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-models, mocking

I gave it a go, but I got the error message `AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute '_state'` for the code below. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Do note at the end of the question I mention that I have tried using patches, without much more luck.

**Model.py**

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    from_product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    from_til = models.ForeignKey(Til)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('sale_date', editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.from_product, self.price, self.create_date)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.create_date = timezone.now()

        super(Sale, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**test_models.py**

```
class SaleModelTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(SaleModelTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.product = MagicMock(spec=Product)
        cls.til = MagicMock(spec=Til)
        cls.price = 2.34

    def test_create_sale(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        with mock.patch('django.utils.datetime_safe.datetime') as dt_mock:
            dt_mock.now().return_value = now
            new_sale = Sale.objects.create(from_product=self.product, from_til = self.til,
                                       price=self.price)
            self.assertTrue(isinstance(new_sale, Sale))
            self.assertEqual(new_sale.create_date, now)
```

I have been reading around and getting quite confused. If I understood correctly I can replace `Sale.objects` with `@patch('app.models.Sale.objects')`, which is placed above `class SaleModelTestCase(TestCase):` and include an extra mock_sale parameter.

I gave that a go too, but `self.assertTrue(isinstance(new_sale, Sale))` returns `False is not true`.

If anyone is about to show me where I am going wrong, I would be very grateful.